# How to respond a mouse message about right-button in listbox item?

Tags: c, winapi, listbox, right-click

If i use the win32 api,how to respond WM_RBUTTONUP?

```
case WM_RBUTTONUP:
{
    break;
}
case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    switch (wmId) {
    case IDE_FRIEND:
    {
        switch (wmEvent) {
        case WM_RBUTTONUP:
        {
            POINT pt;
            GetCursorPos(&pt);
            TrackPopupMenu(g_hMenu, TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, pt.x, pt.y, 0, hWnd, nullptr);
            break;
        }
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    }
```

When I click the right mouse button,it will not enter 'case WM_RBUTTONUP'

'IDE_FRIEND' is associated with listbox.

Comment: The high word of `lParam` on `WM_COMAND` is NOT a message code. The entirety of `lParam` is the window handle that generated the `WM_COMMAND`; you have no way of knowing what button caused the `WM_COMMAND`. You will need to solve this problem some other way. What exactly do you want to do, just show a popup menu for the listbox items?

Comment: to andlabs :I use the wmEvent before,and it also will not work.Yes,I want show a popup menu for the lisbox item.

Comment: WM_RBUTTONUP will work if you right click in the window, but if you right-click in the list-box it won't show up there. You have to create a separate wndProc for the list box (lets call it listBoxProc) then catch WM_RBUTTONUP in listBoxProc. If you had a ListView control you would be able to catch right-click directly. Ps, you should be able to catch `WM_CONTEXTMENU` it's basically the same thing.

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani: Can you tell me how to separate wndProc for the list box ? Is createwindow("listbox"...) then setwindowlong(,GWL_WNDPROC,...)?

Comment: HaibaraAi you have to use subclass, I made an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on listbox will generate context message for parent window. You should be able to catch it like this:

```
case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
{
    if (hListBox == (HWND)wParam)
    {
        int x = LOWORD(lParam);
        int y = HIWORD(lParam);
        TrackPopupMenu(g_hMenu, TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, x, y, 0, hWnd, nullptr);
    }
    break;
}

case WM_RBUTTONUP:
{
    //main window's right-click message
    break;
}

case WM_COMMAND:
{
    //...
}
```

Edit:
To do the same thing with subclass

```
#include "CommCtrl.h" //may need to add this
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")

LRESULT CALLBACK ListBoxProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp,
                                 UINT_PTR, DWORD_PTR)
{
    switch (msg){

    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
    {
        //add listbox menu here
        break;
    }

    case WM_NCDESTROY://safely remove subclass
    {
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, ListBoxProc, 0);
        return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }

    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    //...
    case WM_CREATE:
        ListBox = CreateWindow(L"listbox", ... )
        SetWindowSubclass(ListBox, ListBoxProc, 0, 0);
    //...
}
```